# ogr2ogr ignores some osm ways when converting from osm to gpkg

Tags: gdal, openstreetmap, ogr2ogr

I convert OSM PBF downloaded from Geofabrik to GeoPackage for further processing with fiona. Recently I have noticed that some ways get lost during the transfer. In particular the way with id 8597172 (closed polygon) does not appear in the output GeoPackage. I have uncommented report_all_ways=yes in the osmconf.ini, but it did not make any difference.
Strangely enough it works if I crop surrounding area with osmosis and transform to GeoPackage from the resulting cropped osm.

I am using GDAL 3.3.0 from Homebrew if this is of any help. Below is the XML code of the affected way.

```
<way id="8597172" version="33" timestamp="2019-09-14T02:40:25Z">
    <nd ref="4161854655"/>
    <nd ref="4161854662"/>
    <nd ref="4161854658"/>
    <nd ref="4069748191"/>
    <nd ref="4062922666"/>
    <nd ref="4062922665"/>
    <nd ref="4062922664"/>
    <nd ref="349110075"/>
    <nd ref="4340406082"/>
    <nd ref="4340406083"/>
    <nd ref="349110080"/>
    <nd ref="4062922657"/>
    <nd ref="4062922656"/>
    <nd ref="4062922655"/>
    <nd ref="61076891"/>
    <nd ref="4062922654"/>
    <nd ref="4062922651"/>
    <nd ref="4062922653"/>
    <nd ref="4382307521"/>
    <nd ref="4382307515"/>
    <nd ref="4382307504"/>
    <nd ref="4062922652"/>
    <nd ref="61076892"/>
    <nd ref="3507398896"/>
    <nd ref="4062922650"/>
    <nd ref="61076893"/>
    <nd ref="4062922649"/>
    <nd ref="3507398893"/>
    <nd ref="4281349324"/>
    <nd ref="4281349341"/>
    <nd ref="4281349327"/>
    <nd ref="4066763377"/>
    <nd ref="4281349337"/>
    <nd ref="4281349329"/>
    <nd ref="4382307550"/>
    <nd ref="4281349335"/>
    <nd ref="4161854644"/>
    <nd ref="25246083"/>
    <nd ref="4281349325"/>
    <nd ref="288075197"/>
    <nd ref="288075196"/>
    <nd ref="288075207"/>
    <nd ref="288075194"/>
    <nd ref="288075193"/>
    <nd ref="5337367599"/>
    <nd ref="25246085"/>
    <nd ref="4161854656"/>
    <nd ref="4161854665"/>
    <nd ref="4161854657"/>
    <nd ref="4161854655"/>
    <tag k="dog" v="no"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Kasinonranta"/>
    <tag k="phone" v="0931071473"/>
    <tag k="natural" v="beach"/>
    <tag k="surface" v="sand"/>
    <tag k="website" v="https://www.hel.fi/helsinki/fi/kulttuuri-ja-vapaa-aika/liikunta/ulkoliikuntapaikat/maauimalat-ja-uimarannat/lauttasaaren-uimaranta"/>
    <tag k="loc_name" v="Kassari"/>
    <tag k="official_name" v="Lauttasaaren uimaranta"/>
  </way>
```